# custom error message in IIS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, iis, asp-classic

In IIS 5.1, i have set the website security to Basic Authentications and i have set the page for custom error in IIS which is directing to c:\test.asp file.

When user try to access the website, the user name and password screen comes up and after entering the wrong password 3 times, system shows the custom error page which is fine but why does system prompt for the user name and password again (for three times)?

I don't want user login screen on custom error page.

I have tried to put the custom error page on the default website and set the security to anonymous but it still shows login screen on custom error page.

Anyway to bypass it?

Comment: We have got sharpoint 2001 site which is using default logon script written in asp classic. I want to receive an email when user enters wrong password for three times so i can reset it for him. Can post that script later.

Comment: Just curious: why still IIS 5.1? No possibility for an upgrade?

Comment: This problem has been resolved now by removing the entry on the custom page.

Comment: Could you describe your solution in an answer? This way the next person can learn from it. You can tag your own answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved by adding html page for error 401 and 402.

Answer (score 0):

I think custom error pages should be used when unhandled exceptions occur or any other unexpected behaviour. I think you'd be better of creating a account locked dialog or screen to inform the user they have entered their password wrong three times and it's been locked.

As far as your login screen, how is it being displayed? What is it? It sounds like it'll appear no matter what else is happening.

Comment: This does not seem to answer OP's question. This is a comment on the question. You can add comments to a question by clicking `add comment` just below the other comments.